# How can i call URL's from text file one by one

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to parse on one website with some URL's and i created a text file has all links that i want to parse. How can i call this URL's from the text file one by one on python program.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.example.com").content, "html.parser")

for d in soup.select("div[data-selenium=itemDetail]"):
    url = d.select_one("h3[data-selenium] a")["href"]
    upc = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser").select_one("span.upcNum")
    if upc:
        data = json.loads(d["data-itemdata"])
        text = (upc.text.strip())
        print(upc.text)
        outFile = open('/Users/Burak/Documents/new_urllist.txt', 'a')
        outFile.write(str(data))
        outFile.write(",")
        outFile.write(str(text))               
        outFile.write("\n")
        outFile.close()
```

**urllist.txt**

```
https://www.example.com/category/1
category/2
category/3
category/4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a context manager :

```
with open("/file/path") as f:
    urls = [u.strip('\n') for u in f.readlines()]
```

You obtain your list with all urls in your file and can then call them as you like.

Comment: I've edited my question. I wasn't able run the code the way i want it. Could you please take a look.

Comment: What's wrong with your code ? What is the error it returned you ?

Comment: The code is working if i put the links one by one but i created list which has all links that i want to crawl. Instead of put links one by one get the links from the txt file, once it crawled first link then continue to next one.

Comment: What you are trying to do is to dump a json into a .txt ?
What is the urllist.txt that you gave us in example ?

Comment: What i'm saying is that, is there any way to do, if i create txt file which has all links that i want to crawl it. let's say i have 20 links on that txt file. When i run the program crawled first link then pass to other then other till the end.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I proposed to you : define the list of **urls** as above using the 'with open' statement to get all the links in your text file, then loop on the list to retrieve information from your websites using beautiful soup.